# How to configure the page to search for external layout code?

Tags: php, templates, layout, external

I'm looking for ways to have my pages search for the page layout from an external template page. Please see the below example.

```
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>


<search for header, css, layout, etc from external page>

Page contents

<search for footer>


</body>
```

Is there any way to do this using PHP or HTML? I want to be able to edit the layout for all the pages without having to do it page by page. I welcome any other means to achieve the same effect as long as it works on all the browsers.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Andrew said, use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)s.  I'll set up 2 basic examples.

---

The simplest, have multiple layout files that are called by your main file(s):

header.php:

```
<div id="header">
    Menu can go here.
    <?php echo 'I make all my files .php, so they can use PHP functions if needed.'; ?>
</div>
```

footer.php

```
<div id="footer">
    <a href="#">Footer Link</a>
</div>
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php include('/path/to/header.php'); ?>
        Specific index.php content here.
        <?php include('/path/to/footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

The other option is to have one PHP file which includes all your different layout elements in functions.  The reason I like this, is because you can include one file and then call specific functions for different parts.  This can also be used to pass variables like a title of a page.

layout.php

```
<?php
function makeHeader($title) {
    return 'My title is: '.$title;
}

function makeFooter() {
    $html = '
        <div id="footer">
            <a href="#">Footer Link</a>
        </div>
    ';
    return $html;
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php include('/path/to/include.php'); ?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php echo makeHeader('Page Title'); ?>
        Specific index.php content here.
        <?php echo makeFooter(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Just make sure you use relative paths (`no http://www.`) when including files.  This will allow variables and functions to transfer over smoothly.  The easiest way to do this is using the PHP variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` so if you have a file http://mysite.com/includes/layout.php, you could include it with `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/layout.php')` no matter where your file you are including from is located.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the sort of thing that PHP is for.  A PHP script can include the contents of another script using the `include` statement.

So each page in your application could have an associated PHP script that generates the contents, and includes `footer.php` for the footer layout.  In this way, when you change `footer.php` all the pages that use it will automatically get the changes.

You can't do this with pure HTML, though you could with some javascript and Ajax.